# Tomcat Connection Pool to Oracle RAC

Tags: oracle, tomcat, database-connection, connection-pooling

Our application connects to Oracle RAC cluster using tomcat connection pool.
One node in the cluster had an issue and went to hung state .

In order to ensure the application is not impacted , we would like to know the in depth status of the connection pool . For eg: are all connections to a particular node in RAC is having an issue . From the list of health check parameters , we could not find a way to identify which group of connection connecting to a RAC is affected

If yes , we can take corrective action based on it ( either manually or automate the replacement of connection pool to the RAC node which is working )

Let us know if anybody has faced such issue

Thanks

Lives